# Unconditional layout inflation from view adapter. kotlin

Tags: android-layout, android-studio, kotlin

I am getting following warning in Android Studio: 
"Unconditional layout inflation from view adapter: Should use View Holder pattern (use recycled view passed into this method as the second parameter) for smoother scrolling." on inflater.inflate(R.layout.animal_ticket, null) line.

How do I fix the warning? I am not able to find solution for that problem.

Thanks!

```
override fun getView(p0: Int, p1: View?, p2: ViewGroup?): View {
        val animal = listOfAnimals[p0]
        val inflater = LayoutInflater.from(context)
        var holder = ViewHolder()
        val myView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.animal_ticket, null)
        myView.tvName.text = animal.name!!
        myView.tvDes.text = animal.description!!
        myView.jvAnimalImage.setImageResource(animal.image!!)
        return myView
    }
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For any RecyclerView, you need your own ViewHolder class that has all of the views listed inside `animal_ticket`.

Basically, it works like this:

1) Create ViewHolder that 'holds' all of the views of the item you want to display;

2) Bind the ViewHolder to the RecyclerView and assign values to the views inside;

Here is a example adapter I wrote :

```
class MyActivity : Activity() {
//users is the list we're going to use to get information for the views
val users = ArrayList<User>()
//...getting user information
//.. your activity stuff here

//Creating our adapter
/* 
  Note that to extend the RecyclerView.Adapter, you need to specify a
  ViewHolder. The code becomes much easier to manage if you just put the 
  ViewHolder inside your adapter.
*/
inner class MyAdapter : RecyclerView.Adapter<MyAdapter.MyViewHolder>() {

    //This is the view holder
    inner class MyViewHolder(itemView: View) : RecyclerView.ViewHolder(itemView) {
        //Here you declare your views and get them from the itemView
        //The itemView is one that is passed each time to the RecyclerView
        //(the items inside your XML layout file)
        internal val userImageView = itemView.findViewById(R.id.userImage)
        internal val userFullName = itemView.findViewById(R.id.userName)
    }

    //This is where you return your own ViewHolder with your layout
    override fun onCreateViewHolder(parent: ViewGroup, viewType: Int): MyViewHolder {
        val layoutInflater = LayoutInflater.from(parent.context)
        //user_list_item.xml is below
        val itemView = layoutInflater.inflate(R.layout.user_list_item, parent, false))
        return MyViewHolder(itemView)
    }


    //In here is where you want to set your values for the views
    override fun onBindViewHolder(holder: SentRequestViewHolder, position: Int) {
        val currentUser = users[position]

        holder.userImage.drawable = currentUser.drawable
        holder.userFullName.text = currentUser.name
    }

    //You must override this method as well for the adapter to work properly
    override fun getItemCount() = users.size
}
```

You have to override these methods when using a RecyclerView.Adapter

Here is the user_list_item.xml

```
<RelativeLayout 
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="100dp">

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/userImage"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"/>

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/userName"
        android:layout_below="@id/userImage"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"/>

 </RelativeLayout>
```

Comment: Good advice, but given the fact that the question uses `override fun getView`, OP is likely using `ListView`/`Adapter` and not `RecyclerView`/`RecyclerView.Adapter`.

Answer (score 3):

If there was previously another `View` of the same view type (`getItemViewType(position: Int)` returned the same value) that scrolled off screen, the list view may pass in that instance as the second parameter to `getView()`. It will be faster to reuse that view than to inflate a new one.

You should also use the `ViewHolder` to cache things about the view, such as the relatively expensive `findViewById()`. You can attach it to and retrieve it from the view by tag.

```
override fun getView(position: Int, convertView: View?, parent: ViewGroup?) {
    val animal = listOfAnimals[position]
    val myView = convertView ?:
        LayoutInflater.from(context).inflate(R.layout.animal_ticket, parent, false)
    val holder = myView.tag as? ViewHolder ?: ViewHolder(myView)
    myView.tag = holder
    holder.tvName.text = animal.name!! // etc
}

class ViewHolder(view: View) {
    val tvName: TextView = view.name // etc
}
```